# issue with pagebeforeshow event in jqm+phonegap?

Tags: jquery, xcode4, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app using jqm+phonegap. Suppose i have two pages and on the second page i set some parameters (light, restoration etc using selectmenus).On the page1 i have a slider, when i move the slider it will call the function timeCalculation() to calculate time and display on page1 (real time changing of results as i move the slider).
Now, what i want is suppose first time i set all the parameters on page2 and go back to page1 and perform the calculations (works fine). Now, if i change some parameter on page2, i want the slider to be refreshed automatically and display the new results (I'm still on page2, so when i go back to page1 i should see new results).  The problem is i am not able to do so, and only when i click on slider on page1, it updates the value.
So, i dnt knw how to solve this, i was trying to call timeCalculation() each time i change some parameter on page2.
 Now, when i press back button on page2 to goto page1, I want to trigger pagebeforeshow like this

```
$("#firstpage").live("pagebeforeshow", function (event, ui) { 
         alert("test");
             if(i!=null && e!=null && f!=null && o!=null && r!=null){

                 timeCalculation() //calling this function to calculate time.

             }});
 function timeCalculation(){
           // alert("inside");
            string=light;
            str=string.split(" ").join("");
            str1=selCom.split(" ").join("");
            str2=shade.split(" ").join("");
           // alert("test2");
            $.getJSON("appData.json",function(results){
                      i=results[str][dis];
                      r=results.Restoration[res];
                      o=results.Expertise[op];
                      f=results.Increment[inc];
                      lightColor=results[str].color;
                      compColor=results[str1].color;
                      e=results[str1][str2];
                      });


            finalResult=1000*(e/i)/(f*o*r);
            document.getElementById("result").value=finalResult.toFixed(2);


        }
```

Now, when i click on the back button on page2, alert("test"); statement is executed but it doesn't go to the page1. My app hangs. Please help.

Comment: This is the exact code? Missing at least one piece});

Comment: I agree with @Flatlineato - we need more code to see the problem

Comment: I have edited my question above. plz have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: there is no pagebeforeshow for the first page in a document.

I was having trouble with pagebeforeshow on my 'home' page too until I realized that this event does not fire for the first page in a document. Look at the jQM docs http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html: the pagebeforeshow event is fired by the pagechange method. That method does not apply to the very first page being shown.

There is a workaround, described just below the pagehide event:

> Also, for these handlers to be invoked during the initial page load, you must bind them before jQuery Mobile executes. This can be done in the mobileinit handler, as described on the global config page.